# How to calculate the daily dollar portfolio value in base R

Tags: r, return, finance

I am trying to calculate in a data.frame the daily dollar value of the portfolio in R.

My thought was to create a new column and calculate based on the value every day of an invested amount let's say $5000, I have calculated the daily return already:

[image]

I was thinking of a loop function to first multiply the change in the first row with the original investment and then the value before with the second-row change, but not too sure how would I formulate it to work.

Have tried creating a column and populating with the for loop but unfortunately that doesn't work:

```
BTCdf$growth <- for( i in 2 : nrow(BTCdf)){
x <- BTCdf[i, 3]
y <- x + 1
BTCinvested <- BTCinvested * y
BTCgrowth[i,1] <- BTCinvested}
```

Would want something like this but for the dataset

[image]

Thank you in advance if you are able to help me.

Answer (score 0):

A reproducible sample would be much useful to get the perfect output. Still, you use the `cumprod` function to get this:

```
BTCinvested <- 5000

BTCdf$BTCgrowth <-  cumprod(1+BTCdf$change)*BTCinvested
```

With your example:

```
df <- structure(list(DailyReturn = c(0.2, 0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 0.5)), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

InitialInvestment <- 5000

df$growth <-  cumprod(1+df$DailyReturn)*InitialInvestment
```

Output:

```
> df
  DailyReturn growth
1         0.2   6000
2         0.8  10800
3         0.6  17280
4         0.4  24192
5         0.5  36288
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to calculate your portfolio value would be using `cumprod()` as Mohana suggested above, if you need it through a `for()` loop you must consider the effect of compounding over your investment, so your `BTCinvestment` is constantly multiplied by the ith value +1 of the `change` column:

```
Dailyvalue <- NULL
BTCinvested <- 5000

for(i in 1:length(BTCdf$change)){
BTCinvested <- (1+BTCdf$change[i])*BTCinvested
Dailyvalue <- rbind(Dailyvalue,BTCinvested)}
```

`newBTCdf <- data.frame(Date, close,change,Dailyvalue)`